# Is this 'as such' idiom or not?

Tags: vocabulary

> He had told no one about the marriage. He did not feel it was a
> reason for celebration. Katerina had made it clear that it was a
> purely practical measure, a way for her to get an allowance. ***As
> such*** it was a very good idea, and Grigori would be less anxious,
> when he was away with the army, knowing that she had financial
> security. All the same he could not help feeling there was something
> horribly farcical about the wedding. Katerina was not so shy, and all
> the girls from the boardinghouse were in the congregation, as well as
> several workers from the Putilov plant.
>
> -- *Ken Follett, Fall of Giants*

Does the phrase itself mean [by itself](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_such), or is *as* an conjunction and does *such* refer to something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

1. No, it doesn't mean *by itself*.  When ***as such*** has that meaning, it follows the word or phrase it describes, so it has to be in the middle or at the end of a sentence.  Here, it comes at the beginning of the sentence, so it can't have that meaning.
2. Is it a *conjunction*?  Sure, if you like.  The grammar you're reading about in CGEL doesn't use that term, though.  We can probably call it a *connective adjunct*, if we like.
3. Does ***such*** refer to something?  Well, before we answer this, we should take a look at how ***as such*** is used.

Here's the traditional way of looking at ***as such***:

1. You use the word ***such*** to avoid repeating something.  Therefore, ***such*** should have an antecedent.  In example *1a* below, we repeat the phrase ***a dairy farmer***.  In example *1b*, we replace it with ***such*** to avoid the repetition:

   > 1a. He's ***a dairy farmer***.  As ***a dairy farmer***, he knows a lot about milk.
   >   1b. He's ***a dairy farmer***.  As ***such***, he knows all about milk.
2. This adjunct should have an implied subject, present in the main clause.  In our example, the implied subject is ***he***:

   > 2a. He's a dairy farmer.  As a dairy farmer, ***he*** knows all about milk.
   >   2b. He's a dairy farmer.  As [***he*** is] a dairy farmer, ***he*** knows all about milk.

   And when we replace ***a dairy farmer*** with ***such*** to avoid repetition, we have the same requirement:

   > 2c. He's a dairy farmer.  As such, ***he*** knows all about milk.
   >   2d. He's a dairy farmer.  As [***he*** is] such, ***he*** knows all about milk.

If you want to be prescriptively correct, as you might when taking an English test, you should follow these two requirements.  You need an antecedent for ***such*** before you use it, and you need a subject for ***as such*** after you use it.  People may complain that your usage is wrong if you don't!

However, in common usage, both requirements are dropped.  People use ***as such*** without an antecedent, and they use it when it can't possibly predicate on the subject from the main clause.  When they do, it's essentially a synonym of ***therefore*** or ***thus***.

So your question is: which is it?

- Is it a traditional ***as such*** with an antecedent and an implied subject?
- Or does it just mean ***therefore***?

To answer this, let's look at your example and see if we can find an antecedent:

> He had told no one about ***the marriage***<sub>i</sub>. He did not feel ***it***<sub>i</sub> was a reason for celebration. Katerina had made it clear that ***it***<sub>i</sub> was a purely practical measure, a way for her to get an allowance. As such ***it***<sub>i</sub> was a very good idea, and Grigori would be less anxious, when he was away with the army, knowing that she had financial security.

The noun phrases I've marked with subscript <sub>i</sub> are co-indexed.  That means they refer to the same thing; in each case ***it*** refers to ***the marriage***.

So the subject of our ***as such*** sentence refers to ***the marriage***.  If we work backwards from ***as such*** and find the most recent copular construction ("A is B") that refers to the marriage, we find that the marriage was "a purely practical measure, a way for her to get an allowance".  That sure looks like an antecedent to me!

Let's try substituting it in for ***such***:

> He had told no one about the marriage<sub>i</sub>. He did not feel it<sub>i</sub> was a reason for celebration. Katerina had made it clear that it<sub>i</sub> was ***a purely practical measure, a way for her to get an allowance***. As [it<sub>i</sub> was] ***a purely practical measure, a way for her to get an allowance***, it<sub>i</sub> was a very good idea, and Grigori would be less anxious, when he was away with the army, knowing that she had financial security.

So ***such*** can be construed as having an antecedent!  And the implied subject of that clause refers to the same thing as the subject of the following main clause, so it meets the other traditional requirement too.  This use of ***as such*** meets both of the traditional requirements!

So yes, I think it does refer to something.

Comment: +1 Excellent. But I have methodological qualms about treating *as such* as a reduced subordinate clause; I think *as* here is a [preposition](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/as). But that's just niggling.